# No projects are found to import ,While importing google play service library

Tags: android, google-play-services

I already have google play service library but now i want to import another Google Play service library for some other project. Please help

I am getting this error in project

```
  C:\Android Projects\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__attrs.xml:209: error: Attribute "title" has already been defined
```

Comment: why did you want two libraries ??

Comment: in another project check attr.xml in values. And make sure that there is no title is available

Comment: @user3676184 where to check this attr.xml file and where it is placed.

Comment: res -- values folder

Comment: @user3676184   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <declare-styleable name="FeedComment">
    <attr name="type" format="string" />
    <attr name="item_id" format="string" />
  </declare-styleable>    
</resources>

Comment: @user3676184 the above are attr.xml file code

Comment: please check other xml files in values folder. If there is title available then just rename it

Comment: @user3676184 please hang on i am seeing it

Comment: @user3676184 COULD'T found any file with name TITLE. but still i am getting this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106901/discussion-between-user3676184-and-pir-fahim-shah).